# How to provide a converter that shows up in Convert dialog

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsx, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-sdk

Visual Studio 2010 (and newer versions) has the Convert command in the File > Open menu. I assume this is the right place where custom project converters should be integrated into the IDE.

[image]

This menu command shows a dialog where the user can select a converter...

[image]

I would like to know how a package can provide a converter, that shows up in that dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not documented IMHO (at least I can't find it anywhere). It's based on the content of a file called `convert.dir` located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE` (for Visual Studio 2010). This file may not exist or its size may be 0.

When defined, it contains a list of lines, each line corresponding to a converter. The line format is 5 values separated by the '|' character, like this;

```
relative path to .vsz|relative icon path|localized name|localized description|priority
```

As an exemple, in my old Visual Studio 2008 installation, here is the content of Convert.dir:

```
vsz\VJToCSharp.vsz|images\VJToCSharp.bmp|#VJMigrationWizard.VJMigrationWizard,MWZ_ConverterName|#VJMigrationWizard.VJMigrationWizard,MWZ_ConverterDescription|1
vsz\vb6tovb7.vsz|images\VB6ToVB7.bmp|#MigrationWizard.MigrationWizard,MWZ_ConverterName|#MigrationWizard.MigrationWizard,MWZ_ConverterDescription|1
```

The .vsz file is a standard [Visual Studio wizard file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b48hhx46.aspx).