# How to write Visual Studio Converter

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2017

I would like to write a Converter (usable over *File* -> *Open* -> *Convert...*) so that I can convert build information in non-VS format into a VS-Solution.

Now I could not yet find where in the Extension I can actually create a Converter.

Is there any documentation about all the ways how to extend the VS-UI with the Visual Studio SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's not documented IMHO (at least I can't find it anywhere). It's based on the content of a file called convert.dir located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE (for Visual Studio 2010). This file may not exist or its size may be 0.
>
> When defined, it contains a list of lines, each line corresponding to a converter. The line format is 5 values separated by the '|' character, like this;
>   relative path to .vsz|relative icon path|localized name|localized description|priority
>
> The .vsz file is a standard Visual Studio wizard file.

[How to provide a converter that shows up in Convert dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954342/how-to-provide-a-converter-that-shows-up-in-convert-dialog)

In addition, here is a sample about VSProjectConverter for your reference.
https://github.com/ssvaidya/VSProjectConverter

Comment: But is this still true for Visual Studio > 2013?

Comment: I have researched and could not find related document yet.